# Proposition about rings of fractions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, terminology

[image]

This is taken from Atiyah-Macdonald's Commutative algebra book page 41. Someone please explain to me what is the meaning of "$a$ meets $S$". This is the first time I'm seeing this in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathfrak{a}$ meets S if their intersection contains $x$ non-zero. In this case, the ideal $\mathfrak{a}^e$ contains $\frac{x}{x}=1$.

Comment: The non-zero part is redundant. Usually $S$ does not contain $0$ anyway. Otherwise the localization is the zero ring and we have $1=O$, i.e. the statement above is obviously  true.